# Bootstrap Modal won't POST all data with datepicker field using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have two elements of members data such as id and some other info in a modal which are hidden input elements inside my modal, I bind data from a anchor tag using javascript, example of data element in the anchor tag:

```
data-column="'.htmlspecialchars($column, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8').'"
```

Javascript example to bind into the modal:

```
$('#EnterExpiryModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var memberID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $('#memID232').val(memberID);
        var cola3 = $(e.relatedTarget).data('column');
        $('#column3').val(cola3);
});
```

Having the relevant data for the members in question in my modal (modal code snippet below):

```
<div class="modal" id="EnterExpiryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div id="ExpiryError"></div>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please enter document expiry date</h4>
          <br>
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="ExpiryDateForm">
              <div class="form-group">
              <input id ="memID232" name="memID232" class="form-control" type="hidden">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <input id ="column3" name="column3" class="form-control" type="hidden">
              </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Date</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <div id="date" data-placement="left" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
                      <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" placeholder="Choose Date">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="middleme"><p><i class="fa fa-info-circle iwarner" aria-hidden="true"></i><small> These documents can be uploaded again at any time...</small></p></div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" id="expirySubmit" name="expirySubmit" class="btn clocumsbtn">Confirm</button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

The above code produces the below modal:

[image]

As you can see user is prompted to enter a expiry date in the form field and click confirm.

However the issue I am having is when I hit submit the form does submit, my jQuery validation does all the necessary checks before submitting using ajax, but my hidden input elements don't submit with the values as they should, they appear to be empty, but the datepicker (date) field is populated - I know the values populate with the required data I need.

Here's what the modal looks like without the elements being hidden:

[image]

Here is the validation:

```
$("#ExpiryDateForm").validate({
        rules:
              {


                memID232: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 0
                },

                column3: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 0
                },

                date: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
                }

        },
        messages:
        {
                memID232: "There's an error",
                column3: "There's an error",
                date: "Please enter the expiry date",

        },
        submitHandler: submitExpiryDate
});
```

here's the submit handler:

```
function submitExpiryDate() {
var data = $("#ExpiryDateForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'enterdocexpiry.php',
    data : data,

beforeSend: function() {
$("#expirySubmit").html('<span class="fa fa-spinner"></span>   please wait...');
},

success : function(responses) {

    if(responses=="1"){
        $('#ExpiryError').removeClass('animated shake');
        $("#ExpiryError").fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $('#ExpiryError').addClass('animated shake');
        $("#ExpiryError").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="fa fa-exclamation"></span>   Sorry there was an error!</div>');
    });
    } 

    else if(responses=="updated"){
    $("#ExpiryError").fadeIn(2000, function(){
    $("#expirySubmit").html('<span class="fa fa-spinner"></span>   updating...');
    $("#ExpiryError").html("<div class='alert alert-success'><span class='fa fa-check-square-o'></span>  Added Expiry Date!</div>");
    setTimeout(function(){                          
       window.location.href="manage_docs.php";
    },2000);
    });
    }

    else {
        $("#ExpiryError").fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $("#ExpiryError").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>   '+data+' !</div>');
        $("#expirySubmit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>   Some other error');
    });
    }
}
});
return false;
}
```

here the php:

```
require "database.php";

$memberID = $_POST['memID232'];
$column = $_POST['column3'];

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$_POST['dates']);
$expiryDate = $date->format("Y-m-d");

$docploaded = "Yes";

if (isset($_POST['expirySubmit'])) {

    if ($column == "passport") {

        $statement = $conn->prepare('UPDATE memberdocs SET pexpiry=:expiryDate,puploaded=:docploaded WHERE m_id=:memberID');
        $statement->bindParam(':expiryDate', $expiryDate);
        $statement->bindParam(':docploaded', $docploaded);    
        $statement->bindParam(':memberID', $memberID);
        $statement->execute();

        if($statement->execute() ):
        echo 'updated';
        else:
        echo "1";
        endif;

    }else if ($column == "crb") {

        $statement = $conn->prepare('UPDATE memberdocs SET cvexpiry=:expiryDate WHERE m_id=:memberID');
        $statement->bindParam(':expiryDate', $expiryDate);    
        $statement->bindParam(':memberID', $memberID);
        $statement->execute();

        if($statement->execute() ):
        echo 'updated';
        else:
        echo "1";
        endif;

    }

}
```

Now I have done some troubleshooting and it seems the datepicker is the issue here. If I remove the datepicker (date) form field and replace it with a standard free text input field my form submits successfully with the memID232 input field and column3 input field populated, executing my php script, I've tried to be as clear as possible I hope the screenshots and snippets help, any advice?

Comment: How do you know that the hidden input has the contents of the datepicker? Did you try something a console.log when you leave the date input field? On the other hand, where do you assign the value from the datepicker to the hidden element? The code you posted runs when the modal is first shown, which means the datepicker is still empty. Do you have an event for datepicker input unfocus that will change the value?

Comment: Please show your code that retrieves the values from the form inputs.

Comment: The date will obviously always be empty unless the users enters a date.

_How do you know that the hidden input has the contents of the datepicker?_ Not sure what you mean here, I am using inspect element in Firefox to see that when user enters a date it does pick up the users input. Yes I have a datepicker event in my footer.

Comment: @mjw please see my updated question.